# How do I avoid ExUnit.start() error when running mix test

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When I run `mix test` on my project, I get the following error and I don't understand why:

```
$ mix test
Compiling 2 files (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/myproject_web/controllers/email_controller_test.ex ==
** (RuntimeError) cannot use ExUnit.Case without starting the ExUnit application, please call ExUnit.start() or explicitly start the :ex_unit app
    expanding macro: ExUnit.Case.__using__/1
    lib/myproject_web/controllers/email_controller_test.ex:2: MyProjectWeb.EmailControllerTest (module)
    (elixir 1.10.1) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    lib/myproject_web/controllers/email_controller_test.ex:2: MyProjectWeb.EmailControllerTest (module)
```

I already have a `test_helper.exs` file in `lib/` which calls `ExUnit.start()`. My set up is unusual because I want the tests next to the modules rather than in a separate `test` folder.

Comment: I wanted to share this information as it drove me completely nuts. The first time I fixed it I didn't even know how (I'd deleted and re-made a bunch of files.) The second time I saw it, I knew despair. And then I saw the inconsistency.

Comment: It is important to be sure we are in the root of the project when we run `mix test`. It sounds very basic but sometimes it happens to me that I don't remember that I am in a subdirectory of the project (eg. `lib) and then I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this error comes from the test file having a `.ex` extension rather than `.exs`. With `.ex` then `mix` tries to compile it with everything else before running the tests and then complains because `ExUnit.start()` hasn't been called at compile time.

With the `.exs` extension then the file isn't compiled but is run by `mix test` after the `ExUnit.start()` has been called from `test_helpers.exs`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation of [`mix test`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Test.html):

> This task starts the current application, loads up
>   `test/test_helper.exs` and then requires all files matching the
>   `test/**/*_test.exs` pattern in parallel.

You were right that `.exs` files are not compiled, however this is not a problem if they even were compiled. Tests are run as scripts to avoid repeatedly compilation, since they get randomized order every time, having different output compilation.

The task first compiles all the files, then starts the `ExUnit` and expands all the macros from `*_test.exs` scripts. To prove this take a look at [this piece of code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.1/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L219):

```
defmacro __using__(opts) do
    unless Process.whereis(ExUnit.Server) do
      raise "cannot use ExUnit.Case without starting the ExUnit application, " <>
              "please call ExUnit.start() or explicitly start the :ex_unit app"
    end
```

This means that in files where you use `use ExUnit.Case`, the `ExUnit` server should be up and running at the moment when these scripts are interpreted.

In general in your case, even after changing to `.exs` your tests shouldn't have worked, since with [default configuration](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.1/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex#L464) the path for tests is:

```
 defp default_test_paths do
    if File.dir?("test") do
      ["test"]
    else
      []
    end
```

Instead you should have called the tests with:

```
mix test test/some/particular/file_test.exs
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! I did at some point at `test_paths: ["lib"]` to the `project` part of `mix.exs` which is necessary to get this test structure working with plain old `mix test`